# How to give color range to scatter plot for up and down values

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I want to give different color (color range) to my plot based on values > 5 and value < -5 and values between them. Like the attached image, in image there is just 2 color for more than 5 / less than 5 and values between them.

my code is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(S1, S2, color=abs(S1-S2)>5 )) +geom_point()+ smoother
```

[image: Scatter plot image]

Comment: `color = cut((S1-S2), breaks = c(-Inf, -5, 5, +Inf))`

Comment: Thanks jason, how can I create legend based on count, e.g. **g >5 : 80**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution creating a new variable corresponding to color groups before the `ggplot` :

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(1000,1,10))
df$y = df$x + rnorm(1000,1,5)

df$col = NA
df$col[(df$x - df$y) > 5] = "g1"
df$col[(df$x - df$y) < 5 & (df$x - df$y) > -5] = "g2"
df$col[(df$x - df$y) < -5] = "g3"

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = col)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

EDIT
If you want to label legend with number of observations, and choose the colors:

```
library(plyr)
df_labels = ddply(df, "col", summarise, n = n())

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = col)) + geom_point() + 
scale_color_manual(labels = df_labels$n, values = c("g1" = "red", "g2" = "blue", "g3" = "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, how can I give count number in legend? like this, e.g. **g1 : 87** .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your color calculation gets a result of 3 values:

```
ggplot(data, aes(S1, S2, color=factor(ifelse(S1-S2>5,1,ifelse(S2-S1>5,2,4)) , labels = c("less","more","same")))) +geom_point()
```

Or make this in another step in your script before plotting.